# How can I re-enable the stm32f103's external interrupt after I disable it?

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I use

```
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd=ENABLE; 
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

to enable the interrupt and then use

```
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd=DISABLE; 
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

to disable it. So how can I re-enable the interrupt, use ICER,ISER or any other ways?

Comment: do not use SPL or HAL for that

Comment: See also: [What are the various ways to disable and re-enable interrupts in STM32 microcontrollers in order to implement atomic access guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71626597/4561887)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable and disable interrupts in *NVIC*, just use the relevant *CMSIS* functions:

```
void NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
void NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are CMSIS library functions to enable the interrupts and disable the interrupts.

using `void NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);` you can re enable the disabled interrupt.

you need to mention the IRQ number for your interrupt to enable it again.

However if you want to enable or disable all interrupts in one go, then you must use ARM functions in STM32. these are

```
__disable_irq();
__enable_irq();
```

By using these you can pretty mush enable disable all the interrupts on ARM core.