# What are the various ways to disable and re-enable interrupts in STM32 microcontrollers in order to implement atomic access guards?

Tags: c, stm32, atomic, interrupt, isr

The standard technique to enforce atomic access to volatile variables shared with ISRs, via "atomic access guards" or "interrupt guards", in particular when running a **bare metal, single-threaded cooperative multi-tasking application with no operating system**, is as follows:

```c
// 1. save interrupt state
// 2. disable only the interrupts necessary

// You get atomic access to volatile variables shared with ISRs here,
// since ISRs are the only other "context" or running "thread" which
// might attempt to modify a shared memory block or variable.

// 3. restore interrupt state
```

See also where I describe this in detail here, including best practices (keep interrupts off for short period of time) and **how to do atomic reads withOUT disabling interrupts first**, via my `doAtomicRead()` repeat-read-loop function: [Reading a 64 bit variable that is updated by an ISR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71625693/4561887).

I have previously documented how to do this for AVR microcontrollers/Arduino: [How do I force atomicity in Atmel AVR mcus/Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693278/4561887).

But, how do I do this for STM32 microcontrollers? I know there are a lot of ways.

Please cover the following techniques:

1. Via ARM-core CMSIS:

   1. for global interrupts
   2. for specific IRQs (Interrupt Requests)
2. Via STM32 HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer)
3. Via FreeRTOS

This answer is related, but insufficient: [How can I re-enable the stm32f103's external interrupt after I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68245319/4561887)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update 10 May 2023: one of my primary motivating factors in learning this stuff was related to my first ever ring buffer implementation I wrote 7 years ago in 2016, leading to [this debugging problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36381932/4561887) where I lost 25 hours of debugging work in 2 days. I finally wrote a really good ring buffer implementation that is **lock-free** when used on any system which supports C11 or C++11 atomic types. It is the best implementation I've ever written, and also the best I've ever seen. It solves a lot of the problems of other implementations. Full details are in the top of the file. It runs in both C *and* C++. You can see the full implementation here: [containers_ring_buffer_FIFO_GREAT.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/containers_ring_buffer_FIFO_GREAT.c) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

---

### Multiple ways to enable/disable interrupts in STM32 mcus

...to enable atomic access (critical section) guards:

### 1. **Via ARM-core CMSIS:**

#### 1.A. For global interrupts

```c
__enable_irq()   // enable all interrupts
__disable_irq()  // disable all interrupts

// Returns the current state of the priority mask bit from the Priority Mask
// Register. [0 if global interrupts are **enabled** and non-zero if they
// are **disabled**]
__get_PRIMASK()
```

For the definition of these functions, see:

1. https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h

   1. Contains at least:

      ```c
      __enable_irq() 
      __disable_irq()
      __get_PRIMASK()
      __set_PRIMASK()
      ```
2. STM32 example location: "stm/stm32f2xx/st_hal_v1.1.3/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h":

To **save and restore the interrupt state**, use `__get_PRIMASK()`, like this:

```c
// 1. back up interrupt state; `__get_PRIMASK()` returns 0 if interrupts
// are **enabled**, and non-zero if they are **disabled**.
bool interrupts_enabled = (__get_PRIMASK() == 0);

// do stuff

// 2. Disable interrupts
__disable_irq();
// 3. Restore backed-up-state
if (interrupts_enabled) {
    __enable_irq();
}
```

When dealing with global interrupts, this is the best way for bare-metal, non-FreeRTOS code!

I *think* this technique is also cross-compatible with ALL ARM-core mcus, not just STM32.

I first learned this technique from Tilen Majerle, here: https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2015/06/how-to-properly-enabledisable-interrupts-in-arm-cortex-m/. His work and contributions to clear up this super-obfuscated stuff are infinitely valuable and appreciated!

His example:

> ```c
> void ImportantFunction1(void) {
>     /* Important function 1 */
>     uint32_t prim;
>     
>     /* Do some stuff here which can be interrupted */
>     
>     /* Read PRIMASK register, check interrupt status before you disable them */
>     /* Returns 0 if they are enabled, or non-zero if disabled */
>     prim = __get_PRIMASK();
>     
>     /* Disable interrupts */
>     __disable_irq();
>     
>     /* Do some stuff here which can not be interrupted */
>     
>     /* Call subfunction */
>     ImportantFunction2();
>     
>     /* Do some stuff here which can not be interrupted */
>     /* This part is still interrupt safe because ImportantFunction2 will not enable interrupts */
>     
>     /* Enable interrupts back */
>     if (!prim) {
>         __enable_irq();
>     }
>     
>     /* Do some stuff here which can be interrupted */
> }
> ```

#### 1.B. For specific IRQs (Interrupt Requests)

**It is best to *avoid disabling global interrupts*, if possible,** and disable only the *fewest number of specific interrupts possible* to achieve atomicity for your specific code. So, using these functions allows you to enable or disable only the *specific interrupts* you need to!

Enable or disable *specific types* of interrupts:

```c
void NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
void NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
```

NVIC stands for "Nested Vector Interrupt Controller". *Nested interrupts* (meaning: a higher-priority interrupt can still fire within an ISR) are *enabled* by default on STM32 microcontrollers. Each interrupt type has a priority assigned to it, with *lower numbers* being *higher priority*, and higher-priority interrupts are able to fire while an ISR is being processed for a lower-priority interrupt. See here for a little more information on the STM32 NVIC: https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/05/stm32f4-stm32f429-nvic-or-nested-vector-interrupt-controller/.

Contrast this to AVR microcontrollers (ex: ATMega328 / Arduino Uno), which do *not* have priority-based interrupts, so by default, when *any* ISR is being processed, *all* interrupts (ie: global interrupts) are *automatically disabled* as the program enters the ISR. Note that even on AVR mcus, however, you can still *manually enable* nested interrupts / ISRs if you like by *manually* re-enabling global interrupts inside your ISR, via [a call to `interrupts()` on Arduino or `sei()` (set interrupts) on raw AVR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693278/4561887).

Each ARM-core microcontroller manufacturer, I believe, including STM32 types, *must define and create its own list of `IRQn_Type` interrupt request types*, so see below for the STM32 details on their specific interrupt types defined for each mcu.

### 2. Via STM32 HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) libraries

Enable or disable *specific types* of interrupts:

```c
// enable interrupts
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
// disable interrupts 
HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
```

See, for example: "stm/stm32f2xx/st_hal_v1.1.3/STM32F2xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f2xx_hal_cortex.c/.h" - definitions for those functions above are in those files. See them online:

1. https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF2/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F2xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f2xx_hal_cortex.h#L264-L265
2. https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF2/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F2xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f2xx_hal_cortex.c#L178-L210

Here are the definitions of `HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ()` and `HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ()`. Notice that they just check to ensure your `IRQn` is valid, then they pass the input argument on to the ARM-core CMSIS `NVIC_EnableIRQ()` and `NVIC_DisableIRQ()` functions above!:

```c
/**
  * @brief  Enables a device specific interrupt in the NVIC interrupt controller.
  * @note   To configure interrupts priority correctly, the NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig()
  *         function should be called before. 
  * @param  IRQn External interrupt number.
  *         This parameter can be an enumerator of IRQn_Type enumeration
  *         (For the complete STM32 Devices IRQ Channels list, please refer to the appropriate CMSIS device file (stm32f2xxxx.h))
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_NVIC_DEVICE_IRQ(IRQn));
  
  /* Enable interrupt */
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn);
}

/**
  * @brief  Disables a device specific interrupt in the NVIC interrupt controller.
  * @param  IRQn External interrupt number.
  *         This parameter can be an enumerator of IRQn_Type enumeration
  *         (For the complete STM32 Devices IRQ Channels list, please refer to the appropriate CMSIS device file (stm32f2xxxx.h))
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_NVIC_DEVICE_IRQ(IRQn));
  
  /* Disable interrupt */
  NVIC_DisableIRQ(IRQn);
}
```

For `IRQn_Type`s: see the appropriate definition file **for your specific board**! These are board-specific definitions, for your board from your manufacturer. Here are all of the boards in the STM32 F2xx line, for instance: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF2/tree/master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F2xx/Include. Let's look at the `stm32f217xx.h` file specifically:

1. https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF2/blob/master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F2xx/Include/stm32f217xx.h
2. Raw view (since file is too big to view on GitHub otherwise): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF2/master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F2xx/Include/stm32f217xx.h

From this file, we can see the `typedef enum` definition for the `IRQn_Type`, which is the "STM32F2XX Interrupt Number Definition". Here is what it looks like:

```c
/**
 * @brief STM32F2XX Interrupt Number Definition, according to the selected device 
 *        in @ref Library_configuration_section 
 */
typedef enum
{
/******  Cortex-M3 Processor Exceptions Numbers ****************************************************************/
  NonMaskableInt_IRQn         = -14,    /*!< 2 Non Maskable Interrupt                                          */
  HardFault_IRQn              = -13,    /*!< 3 Hard Fault Interrupt                                            */
  MemoryManagement_IRQn       = -12,    /*!< 4 Cortex-M3 Memory Management Interrupt                           */
  BusFault_IRQn               = -11,    /*!< 5 Cortex-M3 Bus Fault Interrupt                                   */
  UsageFault_IRQn             = -10,    /*!< 6 Cortex-M3 Usage Fault Interrupt                                 */
  SVCall_IRQn                 = -5,     /*!< 11 Cortex-M3 SV Call Interrupt                                    */
  DebugMonitor_IRQn           = -4,     /*!< 12 Cortex-M3 Debug Monitor Interrupt                              */
  PendSV_IRQn                 = -2,     /*!< 14 Cortex-M3 Pend SV Interrupt                                    */
  SysTick_IRQn                = -1,     /*!< 15 Cortex-M3 System Tick Interrupt                                */
/******  STM32 specific Interrupt Numbers **********************************************************************/
  WWDG_IRQn                   = 0,      /*!< Window WatchDog Interrupt                                         */
  PVD_IRQn                    = 1,      /*!< PVD through EXTI Line detection Interrupt                         */
  TAMP_STAMP_IRQn             = 2,      /*!< Tamper and TimeStamp interrupts through the EXTI line             */
  RTC_WKUP_IRQn               = 3,      /*!< RTC Wakeup interrupt through the EXTI line                        */
  FLASH_IRQn                  = 4,      /*!< FLASH global Interrupt                                            */
  RCC_IRQn                    = 5,      /*!< RCC global Interrupt                                              */
  EXTI0_IRQn                  = 6,      /*!< EXTI Line0 Interrupt                                              */
  EXTI1_IRQn                  = 7,      /*!< EXTI Line1 Interrupt                                              */
  EXTI2_IRQn                  = 8,      /*!< EXTI Line2 Interrupt                                              */
  EXTI3_IRQn                  = 9,      /*!< EXTI Line3 Interrupt                                              */
  EXTI4_IRQn                  = 10,     /*!< EXTI Line4 Interrupt                                              */
  DMA1_Stream0_IRQn           = 11,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 0 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream1_IRQn           = 12,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 1 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream2_IRQn           = 13,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 2 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream3_IRQn           = 14,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 3 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream4_IRQn           = 15,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 4 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream5_IRQn           = 16,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 5 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream6_IRQn           = 17,     /*!< DMA1 Stream 6 global Interrupt                                    */
  ADC_IRQn                    = 18,     /*!< ADC1, ADC2 and ADC3 global Interrupts                             */
  CAN1_TX_IRQn                = 19,     /*!< CAN1 TX Interrupt                                                 */
  CAN1_RX0_IRQn               = 20,     /*!< CAN1 RX0 Interrupt                                                */
  CAN1_RX1_IRQn               = 21,     /*!< CAN1 RX1 Interrupt                                                */
  CAN1_SCE_IRQn               = 22,     /*!< CAN1 SCE Interrupt                                                */
  EXTI9_5_IRQn                = 23,     /*!< External Line[9:5] Interrupts                                     */
  TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQn          = 24,     /*!< TIM1 Break interrupt and TIM9 global interrupt                    */
  TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn          = 25,     /*!< TIM1 Update Interrupt and TIM10 global interrupt                  */
  TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQn     = 26,     /*!< TIM1 Trigger and Commutation Interrupt and TIM11 global interrupt */
  TIM1_CC_IRQn                = 27,     /*!< TIM1 Capture Compare Interrupt                                    */
  TIM2_IRQn                   = 28,     /*!< TIM2 global Interrupt                                             */
  TIM3_IRQn                   = 29,     /*!< TIM3 global Interrupt                                             */
  TIM4_IRQn                   = 30,     /*!< TIM4 global Interrupt                                             */
  I2C1_EV_IRQn                = 31,     /*!< I2C1 Event Interrupt                                              */
  I2C1_ER_IRQn                = 32,     /*!< I2C1 Error Interrupt                                              */
  I2C2_EV_IRQn                = 33,     /*!< I2C2 Event Interrupt                                              */
  I2C2_ER_IRQn                = 34,     /*!< I2C2 Error Interrupt                                              */  
  SPI1_IRQn                   = 35,     /*!< SPI1 global Interrupt                                             */
  SPI2_IRQn                   = 36,     /*!< SPI2 global Interrupt                                             */
  USART1_IRQn                 = 37,     /*!< USART1 global Interrupt                                           */
  USART2_IRQn                 = 38,     /*!< USART2 global Interrupt                                           */
  USART3_IRQn                 = 39,     /*!< USART3 global Interrupt                                           */
  EXTI15_10_IRQn              = 40,     /*!< External Line[15:10] Interrupts                                   */
  RTC_Alarm_IRQn              = 41,     /*!< RTC Alarm (A and B) through EXTI Line Interrupt                   */
  OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQn            = 42,     /*!< USB OTG FS Wakeup through EXTI line interrupt                     */    
  TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQn         = 43,     /*!< TIM8 Break Interrupt and TIM12 global interrupt                   */
  TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQn          = 44,     /*!< TIM8 Update Interrupt and TIM13 global interrupt                  */
  TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQn     = 45,     /*!< TIM8 Trigger and Commutation Interrupt and TIM14 global interrupt */
  TIM8_CC_IRQn                = 46,     /*!< TIM8 Capture Compare Interrupt                                    */
  DMA1_Stream7_IRQn           = 47,     /*!< DMA1 Stream7 Interrupt                                            */
  FSMC_IRQn                   = 48,     /*!< FSMC global Interrupt                                             */
  SDIO_IRQn                   = 49,     /*!< SDIO global Interrupt                                             */
  TIM5_IRQn                   = 50,     /*!< TIM5 global Interrupt                                             */
  SPI3_IRQn                   = 51,     /*!< SPI3 global Interrupt                                             */
  UART4_IRQn                  = 52,     /*!< UART4 global Interrupt                                            */
  UART5_IRQn                  = 53,     /*!< UART5 global Interrupt                                            */
  TIM6_DAC_IRQn               = 54,     /*!< TIM6 global and DAC1&2 underrun error  interrupts                 */
  TIM7_IRQn                   = 55,     /*!< TIM7 global interrupt                                             */
  DMA2_Stream0_IRQn           = 56,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 0 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA2_Stream1_IRQn           = 57,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 1 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA2_Stream2_IRQn           = 58,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 2 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA2_Stream3_IRQn           = 59,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 3 global Interrupt                                    */
  DMA2_Stream4_IRQn           = 60,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 4 global Interrupt                                    */
  ETH_IRQn                    = 61,     /*!< Ethernet global Interrupt                                         */
  ETH_WKUP_IRQn               = 62,     /*!< Ethernet Wakeup through EXTI line Interrupt                       */
  CAN2_TX_IRQn                = 63,     /*!< CAN2 TX Interrupt                                                 */
  CAN2_RX0_IRQn               = 64,     /*!< CAN2 RX0 Interrupt                                                */
  CAN2_RX1_IRQn               = 65,     /*!< CAN2 RX1 Interrupt                                                */
  CAN2_SCE_IRQn               = 66,     /*!< CAN2 SCE Interrupt                                                */
  OTG_FS_IRQn                 = 67,     /*!< USB OTG FS global Interrupt                                       */
  DMA2_Stream5_IRQn           = 68,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 5 global interrupt                                    */
  DMA2_Stream6_IRQn           = 69,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 6 global interrupt                                    */
  DMA2_Stream7_IRQn           = 70,     /*!< DMA2 Stream 7 global interrupt                                    */
  USART6_IRQn                 = 71,     /*!< USART6 global interrupt                                           */
  I2C3_EV_IRQn                = 72,     /*!< I2C3 event interrupt                                              */
  I2C3_ER_IRQn                = 73,     /*!< I2C3 error interrupt                                              */
  OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQn         = 74,     /*!< USB OTG HS End Point 1 Out global interrupt                       */
  OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQn          = 75,     /*!< USB OTG HS End Point 1 In global interrupt                        */
  OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQn            = 76,     /*!< USB OTG HS Wakeup through EXTI interrupt                          */
  OTG_HS_IRQn                 = 77,     /*!< USB OTG HS global interrupt                                       */
  DCMI_IRQn                   = 78,     /*!< DCMI global interrupt                                             */
  CRYP_IRQn                   = 79,     /*!< CRYP crypto global interrupt                                      */
  HASH_RNG_IRQn               = 80      /*!< Hash and Rng global interrupt                                     */
} IRQn_Type;
```

#### 2.A. Example usage using *STM32 HAL*:

To get *exclusive access* (to ensure strings are atomically printed, for instance) to the `USART1` for printing debug chars via a HAL-based blocking (polled) mode (ie: via `HAL_UART_Transmit()`), you need to disable all interrupts for `USART1_IRQn` by doing the following. (This guarantees you get atomic access to this device):

```c
// 1. Disable the UART IRQ
HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);

// 2. Send your string (in HAL blocking/polled mode)
// Prototype for this function is from 
// "...stm/stm32f7xx/st_hal_v1.1.2/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f7xx_hal_uart.c": 
// - `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, 
//        uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)`
// Note: `huart` is defined by STM32CubeMX as `UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;` 
// in "hal_source/Src/usart.c"
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)my_str, strlen(my_str), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

// 3. Enable the UART_IRQ
// FUTURE WORK: make this nestable/more robust by only enabling the 
// IRQ here if it was previously enabled before disabling it!
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
```

### 3. **Via FreeRTOS:**

The FreeRTOS atomic-access-guard / interrupt-related functions are listed under the "Modules" section of the Kernel Control API here: [Kernel Control](https://www.freertos.org/a00020.html):

```c
taskYIELD()
taskENTER_CRITICAL()            // interrupts off
taskEXIT_CRITICAL()             // restore interrupts
taskENTER_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR()   // interrupts off
taskEXIT_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR()    // restore interrupts
taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()        // interrupts off
taskENABLE_INTERRUPTS()         // interrupts on
```

#### 3.A. Higher-level macros:

1. *These are the preferred macros to use, and are the freertos-recommended ones!*
2. These all support nested calls, and end up calling `portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` anyway, which is the port implementation of the lower-level `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()`, shown below.
3. From: https://www.freertos.org/taskENTER_CRITICAL_taskEXIT_CRITICAL.html

   ```c
   taskENTER_CRITICAL()        // interrupts off
   taskEXIT_CRITICAL()         // restore interrupts
   ```
4. From: https://www.freertos.org/taskENTER_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR_taskEXIT_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR.html

   ```c
   taskENTER_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR()
   taskEXIT_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR()
   ```

#### 3.B. Lower-level macros:

1. These do NOT support nested calls!
2. Official documentation on them is on the main ["Kernel Control"](https://www.freertos.org/a00020.html) page:

   ```c
   taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()
   taskENABLE_INTERRUPTS()
   ```
3. Notes and limiatations:

   1. `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` at the link above states:

   > Normally this macro would not be called directly and `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` and `taskEXIT_CRITICAL()` should be used in its place.

   1. `taskENABLE_INTERRUPTS()` at the link above states:

   > Normally this macro would not be called directly and `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` and `taskEXIT_CRITICAL()` should be used in its place.

   1. Note also that the use of `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` is demonstrated as the technique used to panic inside an example macro definition for `configASSERT()`.

      1. From here: https://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#configASSERT, when used with a debugger, it is defined as:

         ```c
         /* Define configASSERT() to disable interrupts and sit in a loop. */
         #define configASSERT( ( x ) )     if( ( x ) == 0 ) { taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS(); for( ;; ); }
         ```
      2. My thoughts: perhaps in this one case (ie: hard asserting, or panicking), `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` might be preferred over `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` because no amount of calling `taskEXIT_CRITICAL()` from another thread will re-enable interrupts once `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` has been called [I think!?]--rather, one would have to explicitly (and accidentally) call `taskENABLE_INTERRUPTS()` (ex: from another thread) to re-enable interrupts once `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` has been called. In other words, using the low-level `taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS()` call is appropriate here because it will truly cause the system to sit in a loop, as desired, whereas `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` would not.

#### 3.C. Mutexes and other OS (Operating System)-enabled synchronization primitives

Beyond the examples above, you can also use FreeRTOS **queues** (which are thread-safe, *unlike* all containers in the C++ std library), **mutexes**, **semaphores**, **task notifications**, and other synchronization primitives, where able and where appropriate, to protect certain data which is shared between *FreeRTOS tasks* (threads), assuming you are running FreeRTOS.

See the list of these tools here: https://www.freertos.org/a00106.html, and in the left-hand navigation menus once you click on that link.

### 4. TODO: mutex primitives: raw, OS-free *spin locks* via atomic `set_and_test()` (read, modify, write) instructions

1. Add an atomic `test_and_set()` (`set_and_test()` or `read_modify_write()` really makes more sense as a function name for this, I think) demo using ARM-core CMSIS functions, or assembly, or whatever means necessary, to demonstrate writing a spin lock in STM32. I don't know how to do this yet so it will require finding the right function or operation to use. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set#Pseudo-C_implementation_of_a_spin_lock:

   ```c
   volatile int lock = 0;

   void critical() {
       // Spin lock: loop forever until we get the lock; we know the lock was
       // successfully obtained after exiting this while loop because the 
       // test_and_set() function locks the lock and returns the previous lock 
       // value. If the previous lock value was 1 then the lock was **already**
       // locked by another thread or process. Once the previous lock value
       // was 0, however, then it indicates the lock was **not** locked before we
       // locked it, but now it **is** locked because we locked it, indicating
       // we own the lock.
       while (test_and_set(&lock) == 1);  
       critical section  // only one process can be in this section at a time
       lock = 0;  // release lock when finished with the critical section
   }
   ```

   [Here is a spin lock implementation I did in C11 using `_Atomic` types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73819087/4561887). It should work just fine for STM32 as well, and probably compiles to use the underlying exclusive `STREX`/`LDREX` operations to store (write) and read (load), but I'd have to check that by looking at the assembly. Additionally, this implementation would need to be modified to *add safety anti-deadlock mechanisms such as automatic deferral, timeout, and retry*, to prevent deadlock. See my notes here: [Add basic mutex (lock) and spin lock implementations in C11, C++11, AVR, and STM32](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/issues/12)

### 5. See also:

1. [My answer on this for AVR mcus/Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693278/4561887)
2. [My answer on the general practice and demo of *using* atomic access guards, and my `doAtomicRead()` func which ensures atomic access withOUT turning interrupts off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71625693/4561887)
3. [my Q&A] [Which variable types/sizes are atomic on STM32 microcontrollers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52784613/4561887)
4. [my answer] [Programing STM32 like STM8 (register-level GPIO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798443/4561887)

### For Microchip PIC32 microcontrollers

See the References section of my question here: [How to properly count timer overflows to convert a 32-bit high-resolution timer into a 64-bit high-resolution timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77842969/4561887):

```c
unsigned int __builtin_get_isr_state(void)
void __builtin_set_isr_state(unsigned int)
unsigned int __builtin_disable_interrupts(void)
void __builtin_enable_interrupts(void)
```

Answer (score 4):

Atomic access to shared variables should only be achieved by turning interrupts off where more modern alternatives are not available, or sometimes in very simple projects where performance and latency are not an issue.

Disabling interrupts increases the latency of the system in ways which are difficult to predict, and should be avoided wherever possible.

On ARMv7M and higher cores (including all STM32F1xx, STM32F2xx, STM32F3xx, STM32F4xx, STM32F7xx, STM32H7xx, STM32G4xx, STM32L1xx, STM32L4xx, SRM32L5xx, STM32U5xx) atomic access should be achieved using LDREX/STREX exclusive access instructions.  Complex message queues and semaphore systems can be built upon these primitives which do not ever require to disable interrupts.  For an example look at [the semaphore implementation in mbed-os](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/rtos/source/Semaphore.cpp).

The other members of the STM32 family (STM32F0xx, STM32G0xx and STM32L0xx) may turn individual interrupts off using `NVIC_EnableIRQ`/`NVIC_EnableIRQ` or as a last resort turn all interrupts off with `__disable_irq()`/`__enable_irq()`.

Comment: Can you give a demo? Does it work on AVR mcus? STM32 mcus?

Comment: Demonstrate it in code for bare-metal STM32.

Comment: AFAIK, LDREX/STREX instructions aren't available on Cortex M0 cores. Still, std::atomic works for read or write access, but not for ++ or -- . I don't remember which instructions it uses on M0. I haven't tried, but I guess C11 _Atomic works similarly.

Comment: @Tagli You are quite right, I have edited my answer significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use __get_PRIMASK() and __set_PRIMASK() like so:

```c
uint32_t old_primask = __get_PRIMASK();
__disable_irq();
manipulation();
__set_PRIMASK(old_primask);
```

"This looks like it might have a race condition but doesn't. If interrupts were enabled and something interrupts you between the __get_PRIMASK() and the __disable_irq() and disables IRQs itself, it will restore them before it finishes so your 'old_primask' variable will still be valid." [Source](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/8572/disable-interrupts-and-enable-interrupts-if-they-where-enabled)

"For short operations (a few to hundreds of instructions depending on your latency requirements), disabling interrupts is fine and for very short operations usually the most efficient way to do it. For very long operations or anything that has even a chance of blocking on an RTOS operation, a mutex is required." [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/ot4t93/critical_section_protection_by_disabling/)

Comment: This thread chases a vaguely defined problem, which also has a very wide and not easily defined scope. Not surprisingly, there's no silver bullet. You simply have to understand the problem and its particular circumstances,  you have to have a set of possible solutions at hand, and you have to understand, when, how and why to select and apply one particular of them. While bean counters don't want to hear this, this is how microcontroller programming works in general.